# how to delete facebook app requests using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How can we delete facebook app requests using php?

Currently i am using the following code:

```
$facebook->api("/$req_id", "DELETE");
```

But I am getting the following exception:

OAuthException (#803) Specified object cannot be found

Comment: Perhaps the specified object couldnt be found? Does the object by $req_id exist?

Comment: yes.. its fetched from the DB

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Deleting Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/#deleting) part of the [Requests documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests) you should do:

```
$facebook->api("/$REQID_USERID", "DELETE");
```

Notice that the sent id has the form of the request id, then '_' and then the user id.

Comment: It give error message " Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#803) Specified object cannot be found thrown in /facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1340 "

Comment: Some time has passed since I answered this, but if you check out the official documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests - the Deleting requests section) you'll find all the info you need (for php/js/etc).  If you still get this error then it means that the request you are trying to delete just does not exists.. or that you are using the wrong id.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as well

```
$ids = explode(",",$_REQUEST['request_ids']);

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $id . "_" . $user . "?" . $access_token . "&method=delete";
    $result = file_get_contents($delete_url); 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it give error message "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /public_html/fb/index.php on line 160"

Comment: I got this message"{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported method, delete)",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}"